# ANDROID - How I can keep all items from ListView in a Text File, TextView or similar?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a "**Dynamic ListView**" which I keep adding elements into by clicking on items in another "**Normal ListView**".

Later I have one Button, **I need to save all the ListView items when I click on this button** because later I have to display the items in another activity and I don't know how I can display the Listview directly.

- ArrayString
- Text File
- TextView
- EditText
- Somewhere similar

**My problem**

How I can do that?

Comment: I if you only need to display them once I would choose path of using application class to store your ArrayList<String> and then in other activity you can display them, if I understand.

Comment: So you want to know where to store or how to store and load them in another list view?

Comment: @VyprNoch How to store, the place I do not care...

Comment: @XOOLOOO yeah but how can I keep every item in an arraylist?

Comment: As suggested by @XOOLOOO, you can use ArrayList but the values will be lost when user exits your app. If you want that the values should remain even after exit, use Database or SharedPreferences.

Comment: What all items you need to keep?

Comment: I don't know, sometimes 10, sometimes 15, 5...It's a Dynamic Listview, it'll have many items as needed at the time

Comment: I dont need values for the next session

Comment: The items are string values or objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way---

```
//your listview defined
final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

//your listview data, you may have your own data in adapter
String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
"Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
"Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
"OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
"Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };

//keep the data in arraylist and pass as Serializable
final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
list.add(values[i]);
}


//onclick to pass to another activity
prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Current.this, Next.class);
            intent.putExtra("data", new DataWrapper(list));
            startActivity(intent);  
        }
    });
```

**The implemented class that holds the data arrayList -**

```
public class DataWrapper implements Serializable {

       private ArrayList<String> myData;

       public DataWrapper(ArrayList<String> data) {
          this.myData = data;
       }

       public ArrayList<String> getUserData() {
          return this.myData;
       }

    }
```

**To retrieve at another activity-**

```
DataWrapper dw = (DataWrapper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
ArrayList<String> list = dw.getUserData();
```

Comment: I'll try and tell you.

Comment: It is possible to pass ArrayList<String> through Intent without wrapping it: intent.putStringArrayListExtra("some_another_key", new ArrayList<String>());

Comment: @armansimonyan13 - Thanks! I assumed the complex data of any form, not only a string. So that you can use with Serialization. A more generalized scope.

Comment: @VedPrakash - I see, in this case I would suggest to use Parcelable instead of Serializable :)

Answer (score 0):

You could save your list file in the SharedPrefrences as a String, where each item is seperated by a comma.

By saving the list to the SharedPrefrences you can use it even if the app closed since you saved it and then re-opened at another time. **But if you don't want this - use the way @Ved Prakash mentioned**.

Seperated by a comma way:

```
ArrayList<String> yourData =...

private void saveList(ArrayList<String> data)
{
String items = "";
for(String s : data)
items+= s+ ",";

SharedPreferences spf = getSharedPrefernces("myappname_data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spf.edit();

editor.putString("listview_data",items);
editor.commit();
}
```

**Then to get your data back:**

```
private ArrayList<String> getListData(){
SharedPreferences spf = getSharedPrefernces("myappname_data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String raw_data = spf.getString("listview_data","");

String[] items = raw_data.split(",");

return Arrays.asList(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not permanent you can pass String[] or ArrayList to another Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("some_key", new String[] {});
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("some_another_key", new ArrayList<String>());
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the String values you want in SharedPreferences like this.

Concat the String divided by ";" :

```
String list = "str1;str2;str3";
```

Then...

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString("YOURKEY", list);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Retrive the information in other activity:

```
String list = prefs.getString("YOURKEY", "");
if(!list.equals(""))
   String[] listArray = list.split(";");
```