# How to pass Arraylist having type latlong

Tags: android

I want to pass `ArrayList<LatLng>` from one activity to another activity. How can I do that?

```
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
bundle.putStringArrayList("object", markerPoints);
```

Comment: let the `LatLng` to implement `Parcelable`... and see at `bundle.putParcelableArrayList(String, ArrayList<Parcelable>)`...

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780835/pass-arraylist-from-one-activity-to-other?rq=1

Comment: *LatLng* implements parcelable so you can directly use putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value) of bundle.

Comment: Check my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077217/android-how-i-can-keep-all-items-from-listview-in-a-text-file-textview-or-sim/24077630#24077630

Comment: Make it as `static` and access it in an other activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the ArrayList as a Serializable in the bundle

**example:**

```
putSerializable("object", markerPoints);
```

getting the values from the bundle

```
(ArrayList<LatLng>)bundle.getSerializable("object");
```

Answer (score 2):

While sending

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this,destinationClass);
intent.putExtra("object", markerPoints);
```

on Receiving Activity:

```
 getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(
                "object");
```

Given that your objects in `ArrayList` implement `Parcelable`

Comment: bundle.putExtra("object", markerPoints); no such method in Bundle class it is intnet.putExtra("object", markerPoints);

Answer (score 2):

See this and try..

On First Activity put this code...

```
ArrayList <LatLng> markerPoints = new ArrayList <LatLng>();
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("object",markerPoints);
intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
```

On other activity do this...

```
intent=getIntent();
bundle=intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
(ArrayList<LatLng>)bundle.getSerializable("object");
```

Answer (score 1):

Need not use putStringArrayList. Just plain

```
intent.putExtra("object", markerPoints);
```

would suffice.
For retrieving the value,
use

```
markerPoints = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("object");
```

Make sure, that all objects in `markerPoints ArrayList` **implement** `Parcelable`

Comment: bundle.putExtra("object", markerPoints); no such method in Bundle class it is intnet.putExtra("object", markerPoints);

Comment: hello ,How r u?@Nisha